# How can I print in excel with just a single row and header to data view?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

For example if I had Header1, Header2, and Header3. Header 1 at row 7 had a value of test1, Header2 at row 7 had a value of test2 and header3 at row 7 had a value of test3. I need it to print like this

Header1: Test1

Header2: Test2

Header3: Test3

Is this possible to do and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is `Transpose` - rotate data from rows to columns and vice versa.

Assuming your data is in `A1:C7`, copy that and in a new cell (that's not inside the source you just copied), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. From the dialog box that will appear, check the `Transpose` option and click OK.